# When does a giant get a wild die?

Tags: creature-size, d6-system

I'm wondering if I got size correct.

If I have a giant that has the same "agility" base stat as a normal human (so start 2 and max 4) and for example a skill of 1D. If that giant is of size 3 am I correct that he would only have a wild die to hit a tiny human being? Or am I overlooking something there?

Comment: I'm using the ogl there but star wars D6 answers are also possible (as far as I know the rules are identical there in all regards only that star wars has the size classes a bit more abstractly titled instead of size+3, size+6,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No

It's clearly spelled out in the **Scale** section of [Combat Options](http://opend6.wikidot.com/combat-options#toc22) of  OpenD6.

> For most cases, use these rules: If the attacker is larger than the defender, then the scale modifier is added to the combat difficulty (the defender’s defense value) and the damage total. If the attacker is smaller than the defender, then the scale modifier is added to the attacker’s combat skill total and the defender’s damage resistance total.

---

An example: a giant (see p127 of [D6 Fantasy](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4E8EB5s2_xpNDMzYWU4MmEtZjk3Yi00MThkLTgzMTMtYWY1ZDdmMzM2NDM5/view?layout=list&sort=name&num=50&pref=2&pli=1)) & a human Soldier (see p126 of D6 Fantasy) face off.

- Looking at the stat block of the giant, we see that he is considered Large. This translates to a scale value of 6.
- The giant attacks the human: since the giant is larger than the human, the defense value of the human is boosted by the scale value. So the default combat difficulty would be 16 (See [Base Combat Difficulty](http://opend6.wikidot.com/combat)) before other modifiers are added.
- The human attacks the giant: the default combat difficulty remains at 10, but the attack roll of the human is boosted by the scale value. His attack roll would be 3D (melee combat) +6 (the boost of the scale value) against the default combat difficulty (10 +/- other modifiers). The giant however has a similar boost to his Damage Resistance Total (which in this case would just be 6 since the giant doesn't have any armour).

Comment: Back to topic:  how do you get to 16 combat difficulty? (human has 3d so 9 + 6 for the scale would be 15 or am I overlooking something?)

Comment: ah ok then it is clear. the 16 is the PASSIVE one while they took his active one for the example they are giving in the srd (there they had 3+9 against a scale 3 centaur).